# Inequality of (Conditional) Expected Distance

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider any distribution $p(x, z)$. Is the following statement true:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{p(z)}
\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x \mid z)} \| x - x' \| 
\le \mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x)} \| x - x' \|.
\end{align}
This relation is appealing to me as it would bear resemblance to conditional entropy, where we know that
\begin{align}
H(X \mid Z) = \mathbb{E}_{p(z)} H(X \mid Z=z ) \le H(X).
\end{align}
I'm able to prove via triangle inequality that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{p(z)}
\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x \mid z)} 
\| x - x' \| 
&\le 
\mathbb{E}_{x'' \sim p(x)}\mathbb{E}_{p(z)}
\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x \mid z)} 
\{\| x - x'' \| + \| x' - x''\| \}  \\
&=
2 \cdot \mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x)} \| x - x' \|,
\end{align}
but I would really like to know if it is possible to remove the multiplication by two.

Comment: Are you sure this holds ? Supposing $(X,Z)$ is absolutely continuous with joint density $f_{(X,Z)}$ you're essentially asking to prove that $$\int \frac{f_{(X,Z)}(x,z) f_{(X,Z)}(x',z)}{f_Z(z)} dz \leq \left(\int f_{(X,Z)}(x,z) dz\right) \left(\int f_{(X,Z)}(x',z) dz\right)$$

Comment: I'm not sure if the inequality
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{p(z)}
\mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x \mid z)} \| x - x' \| 
\le \mathbb{E}_{x, x' \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} p(x)} \| x - x' \|.
\end{align}
holds. That said, can you elaborate on why proving this inequality is equivalent/similar to proving the expression you wrote?